# how to get mapreduce job number from hive server

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, apache-hive

if use hive cli. the log is :

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 1
```

but in hive server or beeline. the log is :

```
INFO  : Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
```

how can I get the job number ? 
I need calculate job progress and print it..

Comment: You can use HiveStatement to get all querylogs using jdbc please refer to this link: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveStatement.html

Comment: i use HiveStatement , but the return log doesn't contains "Total MapReduce jobs" or "Launching Job 1 out of 1" ..